# Extracting array key values from a Google Sheet to use as markers on a Google Map

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, google-maps, google-sheets-api

So I'm having a bit of an issue extracting array values. Using the code below, I get the following result structure back:

[image: Snap shot of the results that I get...]

However, when I try to access the specific latitude or longitude keys using something like `getLatLng()[0]["lat"]` i get the dreared `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined` - to get the result in the screenshot below I used `console.log(getLatLng());` - I think it might be a scope error, but I just can't see what I'm doing wrong.

My ultimate goal is to extract the `lat` and `lng` values so that I can create markers out of them on a Google Map. Any clarification would be greatly appreciated!

```
'use strict';

var locations = [];
var locationsDetails = [];

var title = "";
var lat = 0;
var lng = 0;
var payload = [];

var detailPayload = [];
var drhTownTitle = "";
var drhCityCouncil = "";
var drhCountryHealth = "";
var drhTourism = "";

function getLatLng() {

    Tabletop.init({
        key: "1R8MLEwewOr1RSiI-2u1fy6VBvqNRtLR3NPBeyeZwmgI",
        callback: myData,
        simpleSheet: true
    });

    function myData(data) {

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

            var geocodeEndpoint = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=";
            var drhTown = "" + data[i]["town"] + ",+South+Australia";
            var geocodeUrl = geocodeEndpoint + drhTown;

            jQuery.get(geocodeUrl, function(geoData) {
                // console.log(geoData);
                title = geoData["results"][0]["address_components"][0]["long_name"];
                lat = geoData["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"];
                lng = geoData["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lng"];
                payload = [title, lat, lng];
                return locations.push(payload);
            });
        }

        getDeets();
    }
}

function getDeets() {

    Tabletop.init({
        key: "1R8MLEwewOr1RSiI-2u1fy6VBvqNRtLR3NPBeyeZwmgI",
        callback: myDeets,
        simpleSheet: true
    });

    function myDeets(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            drhCityCouncil = data[i]["citycouncil"];
            drhCountryHealth = data[i]["countryhealth"];
            drhTourism = data[i]["tourism"];
            detailPayload = [drhCityCouncil,drhCountryHealth,drhTourism];
            locationsDetails.push(detailPayload);
        }

        createMap();
    }
}

function createMap() {

    var markers = new Array();

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 3,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(1, 1)
    };

    // Initiate the map within the map-canvas element.
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    // Create new map bounds object.
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    // Create a new Infowindow object.
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

        // Append a link to the markers DIV for each marker
        jQuery('#towns').append('<li><a class="marker-link" data-markerid="' + i + '" href="#">' + locations[i][0] + '</a></li>');

        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            icon: '/img/unisapin.svg',
            title: locations[i][0],
        });

        // Extend the bounds of the map using the Latitude and Longitude.
        bounds.extend(myLatLng);

        // Register a click event listener on the marker to display the corresponding infowindow content
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infowindow.setContent(''+
                '<div class="info-container">' +
                    '<h1 class="info-title">'+locations[i][0]+'</h1>'+
                    '<a href="'+locationsDetails[i][0]+'">'+
                        '<p class="info-link">City Council Link</p>'+
                    '</a>'+
                    '<a href="'+locationsDetails[i][1]+'">'+
                        '<p class="info-link">Country Health Link</p>'+
                    '</a>'+
                    '<a href="'+locationsDetails[i][2]+'">'+
                        '<p class="info-link">Tourism Link</p>'+
                    '</a>'+
                '</div>');
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));

        // Add marker to markers array
        markers.push(marker);
    }

    // Fit all of the pins into the map view
    map.fitBounds(bounds);

    // Trigger a click event on each marker when the corresponding marker link is clicked
    jQuery('.marker-link').on('click', function() {
        google.maps.event.trigger(markers[jQuery(this).data('markerid')], 'click');
    });

}

getLatLng();
```

Answer (score 1):

Marko, can you pls modify the code a bit and get the Lat/Lng values first. Then write a delay function after getting the Lat/Lng values(I am saying this with an assumption that you are getting Lat Lng values by ajax call which is asynchronous and the control always goes to the next line before getting the Lat lng values and error is thrown.
delay function is just to debug to wait till all the results are populated for Lat Lng before starting using them. Please let me know if this works.

Comment: Hey thanks for responding - you were right, the issue was that it needed to wait for the data to be received - currently i've used a setTimeOut to wait for the data - but i'd love to know if there's a more robust option. Also I have another issue, i need to somehow get the values of `var drhTownTitle = data[i]["town"];
   var drhCityCouncil = data[i]["citycouncil"];
   var drhCountryHealth = data[i]["countryhealth"];
   var drhTourism = data[i]["tourism"];` into the same block as the .get request which gets the geocode data.

Comment: For those following along at home, i've managed to get the whole thing to work - the only issue remaining is finding a better work around beyond using a setTimeOut to wait for the functions to get their respective data sets.